# JQuery Validation for Duplicates in Form Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation

I want to display error for values that are duplicates or not unique, but my form takes in array of inputs, I have checked these questions on jsfiddle, `name = "week[]"` fails but `name = "week"` works fine

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419114/using-jquery-how-can-i-check-that-a-collection-of-input-elements-have-unique-va)
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955536/prevent-duplicate-values-using-jquery-validation)
3. [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419114/using-jquery-how-can-i-check-that-a-collection-of-input-elements-have-unique-va)
4. [Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553866/jquery-elegant-way-see-if-all-input-fields-are-distinct)

Form HTML

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form name = "myForm" id = "myForm" class ="validate">
            <input type="number" name="week[]" id="week1"/>
            <input type="number" name="week[]" id="week2"/>
            <input type="number" name="week[]" id="week3"/>
            <input type="number" name="week[]" id="week4"/>
        </form>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("unique", function(value, element, params) {
        var prefix = params;
        var selector = jQuery.validator.format("[name!='{0}'][unique='{1}']", element.name, prefix);
        var matches = new Array();
        $(selector).each(function(index, item) {
            if (value == $(item).val()) {
                matches.push(item);
            }
        });

        return matches.length == 0;
    }, "Value is not unique.");

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.unique = {
        unique: true
    };
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, for starters, you can't have duplicate `ID`s.

Comment: First of all an `id` should be unique. And please show us your code that validates the input fields... or at least what you have tried so far.

Comment: **Where is the rest of the relevant code?**  Where is your call to `.validate()` and the HTML markup of the form?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are right, @Sparky, I'm sorry, I left that out, but it works now

Comment: So what about helping other people?  If your question is unclear because you left out too much code, then few people will find it helpful.

Comment: Ok I will update the code, Thanks

Comment: I removed the [tag:jquery-validate] tag since you have not shown the `.validate()` method (plugin initialization), and accepted a solution that has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create array of input values with `map()` and then check for duplicates in array and show/hide error message

```js
$('#myForm input').on('change', function() {

  //Create array of input values
  var ar = $('#myForm input').map(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') return $(this).val()
  }).get();

  //Create array of duplicates if there are any
  var unique = ar.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return ar.indexOf(item) != pos;
  });

  //show/hide error msg
  (unique.length != 0) ? $('.error').text('duplicate'): $('.error').text('');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="number" name="week[]" id="week1">
  <input type="number" name="week[]" id="week2">
  <input type="number" name="week[]" id="week3">
  <input type="number" name="week[]" id="week4">
</form>
<div class="error"></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. This method to check for duplicates is better then previous one.